# Sorted lambda key value syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, lambda

```
student_tuples = [
    ('john', 'A', 15),
    ('jane', 'B', 12),
    ('dave', 'B', 10),
]
sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])
```

This key value of `student[2]`, sorts the list with respect to the age.

But `student_tuples[2]` gives a value of the whole third tuple `('dave', 'B', 10)`, not the third value in the tuples of the list, as said.

So, I'm confused how it works. Shouldn't the value given in the lambda, be `student[x][2]`?

Comment: The key is applied "row-wise" if that makes sense. It's not the same as statically indexing the list

Comment: Do you want to sort the  student_tuples so that you can get the ascending order so that when you do student_tuples[0] you get ('dave', 'B', 10)?

Comment: Do you use the return value of the sorted function? Because I think theres no any error.

Comment: It's `student[2]`, not `student_tuples[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

The `key = lambda student: student[2]` tells the `sorted` function what is the criterion on which the elements of `student_tuples` are meant to be sorted.

so the `lambda` function takes investigates each element of `student_tuples` (which is called here `student`) and then takes its second element `student[2]`. The list in then sorted by the value of this element.

In other words, more mathematically, `student_tuples` is the list of arguments (tuples of three elements) for the `lambda` function and the `lambda` function extracts the third element of each argument one by one.

On the other hand, `student_tuples[2]` just means that you want to take the third element from `student_tuples`.

I hope it somehow clarifies how it works.

Answer (score 1):

let us suppose

```
def fun(x):
    return x[2]
foo=[('x',1,2),('y',2,3),('r',1,9)] 
sorted(foo,key=fun)
```

In the above for each call of fun the each tuple of foo get passed to fun.in that tuple we take the second element and sort with respect to that.In the same way in the above question asked by you,works similarly according to this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple points which you need to understand.

1. `sorted(list_name)` does not mutates (alters) the original list.
2. `sorted` function sorts the elements of the list with their first value until and unless you provide a criterion in the form of *key*.

---

*for ex. In your case, the list elements are tuples and so the sorted function will sort these elements by comparing the first element of each tuple.*

---

If you want to change the sorting criterion then you need to provide a **key** and then the `sorted` function will sort the elements on the basis of the criterion which you defined in your key.

3. `lambda` function is a *function-on-the-fly* i.e. you can define-and-call a function simultaneously.

---

*So, In your case by writing* `sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])`. *You are telling python to sort the list named* ***student_tuples*** *on the basis of criterion* ***key=lambda student: student[2]***. *It means it will compare the 3rd element of each tuple of the list* *student_tuples* *and will sort it accordingly.*

---

Now, let me answer your question to the point that

> Shouldn't the value given in the lambda, be student[x][2]

The answer is NO because *student* is just a parameter of the `lambda` function. You could have written **key=lambda x: x[2]**.
Which simply means that instead of comparing **x** for sorting rather compare **x[2]** i.e. **3rd element of every element**.

Answer (score 0):

sorted() functions create a new sorted list from old list.

```
student_tuples = [
('john', 'A', 15),
('jane', 'B', 12),
('dave', 'B', 10),
]
new_list=sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])
print(new_list)

#Result= [('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```